# In Excel, use "Range.Replace" method to substitute characters, but do not affect formulae

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create a macro for Excel (2010) to substitute characters of the Latin alphabet with their equivalents from the Cyrillic alphabet.

At first glance, this seems to be quite easy, e.g. like this:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Z500").Replace "sht", ChrW(1097) '--> щ
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Z500").Replace "Sht", ChrW(1095) '--> Щ
'And so on for all relevant characters and character combinations
```

However, when I run this on my active worksheet, not only the cell values are affected but also formulae. Which makes them worthless, because e.g. Sum(B1:B3) will become Сум(Б1:Б3) [i.e. using Cyrillic letters] which, for Excel, is gibberish.

Therefore the question: is there a way to tell Excel to use the Replace method only on cell values, not on formulae?

Note: a dirty workaround could be to include a procedure that on each cell in the range first checks if it starts with an "=", and if so, leave the cell contents unchanged. But perhaps there is a better, less home-brewed way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Range.Replace` will always search in formulas.

There is a `HasFormula` property in the `Range` object. But for using this you must iterate over all cells in the given `Range`. If this `Range` is quite big then this will take quite long if you are trying `Replace` in each of the cells. So I would only trying `Replace` if the cell is not empty, is not numeric and not has a formula.

```
Sub test()

 Dim oRange As Range

 For Each oRange In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Z500")
  If Not IsEmpty(oRange) And Not IsNumeric(oRange.Value) And Not oRange.HasFormula Then
    oRange.Replace What:="sht", Replacement:=ChrW(1097), MatchCase:=True
    oRange.Replace What:="Sht", Replacement:=ChrW(1065), MatchCase:=True
  End If
 Next

End Sub
```

Oh and you must set `MatchCase` if the replace shall be case sensitive.

**Second approach:**

You also could use the `VBA` `Replace` instead of  `Range.Replace` as showed in the other answer. But not with `Range.Formula` but with `Range.Value`.

This could be faster.

```
Sub test2()

 Dim oRange As Range

 For Each oRange In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Z500")
  If Not IsEmpty(oRange) And Not IsNumeric(oRange.Value) And Not oRange.HasFormula Then
    oRange.Value = Replace(oRange.Value, "sht", ChrW(1097), , , vbBinaryCompare)
    oRange.Value = Replace(oRange.Value, "Sht", ChrW(1065), , , vbBinaryCompare)
  End If
 Next

End Sub
```

Comment: This looks like exactly the elegant solution I was searching for. 'Range.HasFormula' is the element I was not aware of, but felt it should exist. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to look in .Formula properties, default Range result give the .Value (ie result), not value.

I will suggest use a loop like :

```
For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Z500")
    cell.Formula = Replace(cell.Formula, "sht", ChrW(1097))
    cell.Formula = Replace(cell.Formula, "Sht", ChrW(1095))
Next
```

Comment: This does the opposite of what the OP wants, doesn't it?

Comment: Right !
 Like Axel answer so : For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Z500")
    cell.Value= Replace(cell.Value, "sht", ChrW(1097))
    cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, "Sht", ChrW(1095))
Next